# Facebook share button image selection not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have a website page (https://ondeajudo.com/projeto/b710e2eaf38844aabbfc251a46006cde) where I added the meta tags for Facebook images as follows:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044621290.png" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044621290.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044621290.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044684603.png" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044684603.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044684603.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044625413.png" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044625413.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044625413.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
```

When I post this link in my Facebook timeline to share, all images shows up correctly for selection.

[sharing inside Facebook using the page url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24rX0.png)

But when I use the share button inside my website using the Facebook sdk, only the first image shows up and no selection is possible.

How do I allow image selection when sharing through the facebook sdk inside my page?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure that is not possible any more, Facebook removed that from the Share button a while ago.

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044621290.png" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044621290.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044621290.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044684603.png" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044684603.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044684603.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044625413.png" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044625413.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://projectify-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/project_pictures/2017-05-17/f256709d685122ed83feab210cad5557-1495044625413.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
```